# How to compare one character to ALL characters of a String

Tags: java

I have a string that will be different every time you run the code. I want to make an `if` statement that compares *one* char, to *every* individual character of the string. For example, if I were to compare 'c' to cat, it will return that there is a 'c'. BUT If I compared it to orange, it would return that there is not any 'c'. I can't figure out how to do this because the string will change length every time so I cannot simply do c = a && b && c because there could be a d.

Comment: Could you please show codes ?

Comment: @3kings: That would only return `true` if the first letter is a c. `return false` must be placed after the `for` loop, or else it will return `false` on the first letter if it is not a c.

Answer (score -1):

There is `String#contains`:

```
return "orange".contains("c");
```

If you want to do other kind of comparisons (such as that all characters in the String are "c"), you can loop over the characters:

```
for (char c : theString.toCharArray()){
  // do something for `c`
}
```

Or look at regular expressions.